# What is Reference Script Library in asp.net mvc 3?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3

I noticed when you make a strongly typed view you have an option to check a box called "reference script libraries"

http://gyazo.com/289392fc957866f19c4ae6d8b51a037e.png

In my case I don't have any strongly typed views but what references does it add?

Comment: So wait.  You took a the time to take a screen capture, crop it and upload it to a server instead of simply clicking that box and seeing what happened?  ;)

Comment: @jfar - Yep... When I did it I never saw it any references get generated

Answer (score 4):

It just adds this:

`<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

`<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.min.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>`

Comment: when I create a view with the textbox check it never add's these reference. does it add it somewhere else then the view or something since I not seeing it.

Comment: @chobo2 - puts those in the view for me

Comment: Weird but I had problems from asp.net mvc 3 from the start. I had to reinstall VS 2010 because for some reason it would not recognize the razor files. So maybe there is still some underlining problem.